# Your friend is on Instagram notification

Tags: instagram

I have installed Instagram and now it notifies me:

> Your friend bob is on Instagram as bob123.

I don't remember giving it permissions to access my contacts and when I go to Android Settings > Applications > Instagram it does not have any permissions enabled.

How does it know my contacts and how can I disable it?

Note: I do not have Facebook connected. In fact it has a banner across the top of the app asking if I want to connect Facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notifications indicate people who are friends with you on Facebook. If you used "Sign in with Facebook" option or used the e-mail address to sign up on Instagram that you used to sign up for Facebook too. Instagram is owned by Facebook, so they can know.

Comment: They have to be using my email then. I didn't know Facebook owned them.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts It was developed by them. To create more of a photo-blog kind of hype to steal some popularity from Twitter.

Comment: @SarpSTA Facebook acquired them a few years ago, they didn't start it :)

Comment: @MatthewRead For one billion dollars! I just read it. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 1):

After my small investigation I can say that this notification appears when one of your mutual subscribers creates another Instagram account using same phone number. Instagram does not allow to create multiple accounts using same email address, but it does allow it using same phone number.
So, when you have no permissions granted to Instagram and no Facebook connected, it appears that user *bob* just created another account under the name *bob123*.

Answer (score 0):

I also had such a problem and fixed it, for it I need to click on the account and synchronize the account and off ok, I did it